# Material3 is applying to all the components except my AlertDialog widget in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog, material3

I applied the `useMaterial3 : true` in the theme for the app, and it's working fine except for the AlertDialog, and the components within- they are all in material 2.

The project is new, very buggy, not functional yet, and the code is very messy; But here's the gitHub link to the main.dart: https://github.com/amkcodesnreads/rhenum/blob/main/lib/main.dart

The AlertDialog widgets are at the end (there are 2), and they are implemented in the onPress() of the Floating Action Button. Here is the result for one screen:

AlertDialog for one screen on pressing the FAB : -

[image]

The calendar within on pressing the edit button : -

[image]

As you can see, these are in material 2! Please help me change them to material 3.

Trial and expectation: I tried adding `useMaterial3 = true` expected m3 applied everywhere- didn't work.